# Unable to install Angular CLI using node.js command prompt

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, npm-install, angular-cli-v6

I am unable to install Angular CLI on Windows.

I have tried the following:

```
C:\Users\username>node -v
v8.11.3 
C:\Users\username> npm -v
5.6.0 

C:\Users\username>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angularMfcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.94.96:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'
```

Please tell me why it is not working and what I should do.

Comment: You are not connected to internet. Or you are connected but your internet is not working.I can generate same error by diconnecting from intenet and running this installation command.

Comment: Hi, my internet connectivity is fine.. is there any thing to be checked for disabling proxy settings?. pls clarify

Answer (score 0):

This error means your internet connection is not working.

I would suggest you check your internet connection and try again.

Comment: i tried to execute again the command. it stops with [..................] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 9b4febdba945ce88..

Comment: try this:
`npm config rm proxy`     
`npm config rm https-proxy`